# Swift 2.2 - value is not persisted after function execution

Tags: swift, function, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

I created the function above to check if a user exists on Firebase database:

```
func userExists(userUid: String) -> Bool {
    var userExists: Bool = false
    DBRef.child("users").child(userUid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){
            userExists = true
        }else{
            userExists = false
        }
    })
    return userExists
}
```

The problem is that the userExists function always returns "false", even if the userExists variable is setted as true inside the withBlock. Any help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use return and closure blocks in the same function, because the function will return the value before the block is executed. 
You can use something like this:

```
func userExists(userUid: String, completion: (exists: Bool) -> Void) {
    var userExists: Bool = false
    DBRef.child("users").child(userUid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){
            completion(true)
        }else{
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

Then, you just call:

```
if userExists(userId, completion: {
    // Code here
})
```

Comment: It worked, aramusss. Thank you. I just modified the call function

Comment: It worked, aramusss. Thank you. I just modified the call function this way: